# Согласование сказуемого при наличии обособленного оборота

Tags: согласование

**Ведь заповедное дело в Вологодской области, точнее его предпосылки, зарождал(о/и)сь ещё при царе.**

Сказуемое ведь должно согласовываться с делом, а не с предпосылками, так? Или я ошибаюсь? Совсем убрать предпосылки нельзя, т. к. это отрывок из цитаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соглосласование в вашем примере должно быть  с подлежащим, в данном случае  - "дело".

На форму согласования сказуемого не влияет наличие при подлежащем уточняющих или **пояснительных слов, присоединительных конструкций, сравнительных оборотов и т.д., например:** В*се, по-видимому, и даже природа сама, вооружилось против господина Голядкина (Достоевский);  Ср. в периодической печати: Американская творческая интеллигенция, в частности американские кинорежиссеры, переживает сейчас эпоху повышенного интереса к нашему киноискусству.*

**Согласование сказуемого не с подлежащим, а с поясняющими его конструкциями используется для выражения авторского, часто иронического, отношения к предмету речи или всему высказыванию и возможно только в художественно-публицистической и разговорной речи, например:** **Из всех родственников только один человек, а именно восьмидесятилетняя бабушка, продолжала держать сторону бедной Клавы (Сем. Нариньяни).**

[**См.: Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ М.: ЧеРо, 1999**](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_03)